# Constructor in class cannot be applied to given types - Abstract Class

Tags: java, constructor, abstract-class, super

I know titular problems has been already answered here and over there, yet for every answer still cannot solves my problem. The problem is this :

I have abstract class which is Node, containing constructor like this :

```
public Node(List<Record> dataSet, int labelIndex) {
    this.allSamples = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    this.dataSet = dataSet;
    this.classificationLabelIndex = labelIndex;
    this.entropy = 0;
}
```

And then, I extend the absract class into TreeNode, containing constructor like this (to use super) :

```
public TreeNode(List<Record> dataSet, int labelIndex, List<Attribute> attributes, int level, double threshhold) {
    super(dataSet, labelIndex);
    this.attributes = attributes;
    splittedAttrs = new HashSet<Integer>();
    this.level = level;
    this.displayPrefix = "";
    this.children = null;
    this.threshhold = threshhold;
}
```

So, the TreeNode class extends abstract Node class and using super method to call dataset and labelindex from Node class, but then I get warning "constructor Node in class Node cannot be applied to given types, required no arguments." Maybe because I added some parameters in TreeNode, but I still think it's highly unlikely. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Please clarify (or better show the code) when you getting the warning.

Comment: I think it might be because you can't instantiate an abstract class, so it ignores your constructor, just using Object's default one. Just an idea

Comment: It already worked guys, I just need to restart Netbeans... Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing more details, it's hard to know what the problem is.  No, you cannot directly instantiate an abstract class, but yes you CAN call super on an abstract class's constructor from a sub-class, so what you're doing appears to be fine.  One idea is to make sure you don't have any conflicting class path issues with another class called Node or TreeNode.  Actually, you're creating custom classes that might already exist in your classpath if you've imported these, for example:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/TreeNode.html
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html

Try renaming them to something more specific for you like MyTreeNode and MyNode or whatever.

Whatever the case, I tried replicating as best I could with the code you sent and didn't see any issues on my end (i.e. no clashes with other imports  in my classpath).  Check this and see if it matches what you have.  If not, please copy/paste the stack trace of your error, along with all of you code.  Thanks

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public abstract class Node {

private List<Integer> allSamples;
private List<Record> dataSet;
private int classificationLabelIndex;
private int entropy;

public Node(List<Record> dataSet, int labelIndex) {
    this.allSamples = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    this.dataSet = dataSet;
    this.classificationLabelIndex = labelIndex;
    this.entropy = 0;
}
```

}

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

public class TreeNode extends Node {

private List<Attribute> attributes;
private Set<Integer> splittedAttrs;
private int level;
private String displayPrefix;
private Object children;
private double threshhold;

public TreeNode(List<Record> dataSet, int labelIndex,
        List<Attribute> attributes, int level, double threshhold) {
    super(dataSet, labelIndex);
    this.attributes = attributes;
    splittedAttrs = new HashSet<Integer>();
    this.level = level;
    this.displayPrefix = "";
    this.children = null;
    this.threshhold = threshhold;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Node node = new TreeNode(new ArrayList<Record>(), 1,
            new ArrayList<Attribute>(), 1, 1.1);

}
```

}

```
class Record {}
class Attribute {}
```